# E-mail para não aceitar resposta

Tags: email

Estou enviando um e-mail de confirmação de cadastro para um cliente usando o PHPMailer. Gostaria de saber como faço para que o cliente não consiga enviar nenhuma resposta, apenas clicar no link e confirmar o cadastro. Existe algum e-mail padrão para se passado pelo setFrom, como no exemplo abaixo?

$mailTo->setFrom('nao-responda@xxxxxxx.com', 'Empresa');

Comment: Obrigado Ricardo

Comment: Basta usar um endereço inexistente. Convém que seja do seu próprio domínio, para garantir que nunca seja criado, e não causar desconfiança. Se utilizar uma conta real, o cliente vai responder e assumir que vocês receberam e leram, já que não vai ter erro nenhum.